# How can I separate an email from its previous answer

Tags: c#, .net, email, openpop

How can I separate an email from its previous answer? I only want the latest reply

For example:

- Mail 1: Customer sends an email with the text: "Hello"
- Mail 2: I
  answer the email with text figures: "Yes?"
- Mail 3: The customer
  replies: "What are you doing?"

But when I collect these 3 mails with the phrase, GetBodyAsText I get the entire conversation from every mail - containing 1,2 and 3.

I only want mail 3 content. How can this be done?

I've tried several method as for an example, message part, but it does the same, and retrieving mail 1,2 and 3.

Do you have any links where I can read more about it, or code samples?
It must be said that I use OpenPop.Mine.

This is my code:

```
Models.Helpdesk.Email obj = new Models.Helpdesk.Email();

            obj.MessageNumber = i;
            obj.MessageId = message.Headers.MessageId;
            obj.From = message.Headers.From.Address;
            obj.Subject = message.Headers.Subject;
            obj.Reference = message.Headers.References; 

            OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart plaintxt = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();  

            if ((plaintxt != null))
            {
                obj.Body = plaintxt.GetBodyAsText();
            }
            else
            {
                if ((htmltxt != null))
                {
                    obj.Body = htmltxt.GetBodyAsText();
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.Body = "";
                }
            }

            obj.DateSent = message.Headers.DateSent;
            obj.Recvd = message.Headers.Date;
```

This is my email output:

```
Just chillin, you?

Yours sincerely

*Testperson*

Developer

*Companyname *

*emailA@gmail.com 


<http://goog_1337018965/> Facebook <http://www.facebook.com>
<http://goog_1337018972/> Twitter <https://twitter.com/#!> 


D 28. januar 2015 kl. 09.16 wrote Test Test <emailA@gmail.com>:

> What are you doing Dan
>
> D 28. januar 2015 kl. 09.12 wrote Test Test <emailA@gmail.com>:
>
> Hey Steve
>>
>> D 28. januar 2015 kl. 09.09 wrote Test Test <emailA@gmail.com>:
>>
>> Hey Dan
>>>
>>> Yours sincerely
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> *Testperson*
>>>
>>> Developer
>>>
>>> *Companyname *
>>>
>>>
>>> <http://goog_1337018965/> Facebook <http://www.facebook.com>
>>>    <http://goog_1337018972/> Twitter
>>> <https://twitter.com/#!>
>>>
>>>
>>
>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

SigParser's API can split emails like you're requesting for English, German and Spanish. Feed it the body of an email it will give you the body of each email segment in an array.

https://api.sigparser.com/

On the SigParser Try page for previewing how an email parses this is the result of the email in the previous answer.

[image]

This the the API spec for the emails property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to look for a common delimiter between the responses in the email Body. Usually a different response will be delimited by the word "From:", "---Original Message---", etc.

If this is the case, and the most recent response is at the top, you can just grab the first part of the message up to the delimiter. For example, here's a method that could do it:

```
static string GetLastResponse(string message, string delimeter = "From:")
{
    int delimeterPosition = message.IndexOf(delimeter);

    return (delimeterPosition > -1)
        ? message.Substring(0, delimeterPosition)
        : message;
}
```

And then you could just call it like:

```
    obj.Body =
@"Thanks, can't wait to see you!

Thanks,
Dan

From: Jack Smith 
Sent: Tuesday, January 27, 2015 1:15 PM
To: Dan Smith; Ron Smith; Betty Smith
Cc: Jane Doe; John Doe
Subject: RE: Family Reunion

+ Dan

Dan, if you can go, I can go!

Thanks,
Jack

From: Ron Smith 
Sent: Tuesday, January 27, 2015 1:15 PM
To: Jack Smith; Betty Smith
Cc: Jane Doe; John Doe
Subject: RE: Family Reunion

What do you guys think about getting together for drinks on Saturday?

Thanks,
Ron";

    string lastResponse = GetLastResponse(obj.Body);

    Console.WriteLine(lastResponse);
```

And the output is:

> Thanks, can't wait to see you!
>
> Thanks, Dan

**UPDATE**

If you don't have a full string that is the always the same delimeter, you can also split on a common pattern. For example, if you know the delimeter always starts with some text, contains some text, and/or ends with some text, you could use the following method. Note that the delimeter parameters are not required, so you can pass null to one or more of them if there isn't a common 'startsWith', 'endsWith', or 'contains' string:

```
private static string GetLastResponse(string message, string delimStartsWith, 
    string delimContains, string delimEndsWith, 
    StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.Ordinal)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message)) return message;

    var lastResponse = new StringBuilder();
    var lines = message.Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        // Check to see if this line starts with, contains, 
        // and ends with the specified text
        if ((delimStartsWith == null || line.StartsWith(delimStartsWith, comparison)) &&
            (delimContains == null || line.IndexOf(delimContains, comparison) >= 0) &&
            (delimEndsWith == null ||line.EndsWith(delimEndsWith, comparison)))
        {
            // If we get here it means all our conditions were met, so this
            // line is a delimeter and we should break out of this loop.
            break;
        }

        // Haven't reached a delimeter yet, so add this line to our lastResponse
        lastResponse.AppendLine(line);
    }

    return lastResponse.ToString();
}
```

In your example message it looks like the delimeters always start with "D ", contain the word " wrote ", and end with the string ".com>:". If this is the case, then you can use the above function like so:

```
string lastResponse = GetLastResponse(conversation, "D ", " wrote ", ".com>:");

Console.WriteLine(lastResponse);
```

And the output is:

> Just chillin, you?
>
> Yours sincerely
>
> *Testperson*
>
> Developer
>
> *Companyname *
>
> *emailA@gmail.com
>
> http://goog_1337018965/ Facebook http://www.facebook.com
>   http://goog_1337018972/ Twitter https://twitter.com/#!

Comment: Hey @Rufus. I tried your solution but without success. I just posted my email conversation - which seems to be different from yours, since i dont have any "from " as delimiter.

Comment: Is this part the actual text in the email, or did you modify any of it: `D 28. januar 2015 kl. 09.16 wrote Test Test <emailA@gmail.com>:`

Comment: I updated my answer with a new example that lets you specify parts of the delimeter string (instead of having to specify the whole string, since the whole string changes between responses in your example).